# How to rewrite wiki links in Golang?

Tags: go

Been stuck trying to rewrite some text in Golang: http://play.golang.org/p/0hoXx7qA0b5

How do I match several `[[]]` links in a text string?

`log.Printf("match: %+v", match)` doesn't show the log Group matches clearly. Am I missing something to help me work with matches, so I know whether it's a link with a title or not.

Is there a better approach than using regexp?

Comment: regexp is the best approach, you just need to use better expression

Comment: The output is easier to read if you use the `%#v` format. You're also gonna wanna use the "all" version of  FindStringSubmatch, [FindAllStringSubmatch](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch). https://play.golang.org/p/zhBT2W5NREx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `(.*)` is a greedy match hence you should try limiting the first group. Based on your sample input, the `|about` is optional.

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\[\[([^|]*)(?:\|(.*))?\]\]`)

func relink(input string) string {

    var reform []string    
    for _, match := range re.FindAllStringSubmatch(input, -1) {
        name, short := match[1], match[2]
        if short == "" {
            short = strings.ToLower(name)
        }
        reform = append(reform, fmt.Sprintf("[%s](%s)", name, short))
    }

    return strings.Join(reform, "\n")
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/52RPkPuKaHF)

Comment: There is something wrong https://play.golang.org/p/BwN0IRfIPVX https://s.natalian.org/2018-12-09/ssemilla.mp4

Comment: I fixed somewhat https://play.golang.org/p/UlJesqO1obW But still the results upon https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Webconverger/wiki/master/index.mdwn are not as expected! https://s.natalian.org/2018-12-09/ssemilla2.mp4

Comment: Got it! https://s.natalian.org/2018-12-09/working.txt with https://play.golang.org/p/gRQGjHfEtbv